# How to send email using Mail kit from my website domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email, smtp

I want to send an email using a Mail kit, from my website domain.
I don't want to use Gmail or other emails, I just want to send it from the website domain.
info@sigmaworldco.com

This is my code

```
  public async Task SendEmailAsync(Message message)
    {
        var emailMessage = CreateEmailMessage(message);
        await SendAsync(emailMessage);
    }

  private MimeMessage CreateEmailMessage(Message message)
    {
        var email_message = new MimeMessage();
        email_Message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_mailSettings.UserName));
        email_Message.To.AddRange(message. To);
        email_Message.Subject = message. Subject;
        //email_Message.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Text) { Text = message.Content }; // ارسال نص عادي
        //email_Message.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html) { Text = string.Format("<h3 style='color:blue'>{0}<h3>", message.Content) }; // ارسال فورمات HTML

        //----------------------------------Attachments--------------------------
        //var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder { HtmlBody = string.Format("<h3 style='color:blue'>{0}<h3>", message.Content) };
        var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder { HtmlBody = message.Content };
        if (message.Attachments != null && message.Attachments.Count > 0)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes;
            foreach (var attachment in message. Attachments)
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    attachment.CopyTo(ms);
                    fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
                bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(attachment. Filename, filebytes, ContentType.Parse(attachment.ContentType));
            }
        }
        emailMessage.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        return email_Message;
    }

 private async Task SendAsync(MimeMessage mailMessage)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                //client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false; // add this code when hosting the site on web hosting with no SSL certificate.
                await client.ConnectAsync(_mailSettings.Host, _mailSettings.Port, false);
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                await client.AuthenticateAsync(_mailSettings.UserName, _mailSettings.Password);
                await client.SendAsync(mailMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                client.Dispose();
            }

        }

    }
```

And this is my AppSetting file

```
  "MailSettings": {
"DisplayName": "Sigma Oil Company",
"Username": "info@sigmaworldco.com",
"Password": "**********",
"Host": "sigmaworldco.com",
"Port": 465
```

}

Please guys help me, I'm stuck here.
I want to send mail from my website domain([www.sample.com](http://www.sample.com))

Comment: You haven't explained any sort of problem with your code, and you've not asked a specific question related to that code.  You've just told us in general what you want to do and dumped a bunch of code. How exactly can we help?

Comment: You must use a certified email server to send emails.  If you create your own it will only allow emails within your network.  SMTP is the standard protocol to connect an email client to a certified email server.  It is not the protocol where one email server sends messages to another email server (like GMAIL to Outlook 365).  GMAIL will not accept an email message without a user account.  GMAIL will not accept an email from your server info@sigmaworldco.com

Answer (score 1):

MailKit can be a little finicky in my experience, so here are some suggestions:

- Fix the From address like so, `var fromAddress = new MailboxAddress(_mailSettings.DisplayName, _mailSettings.UserName);`
- Try connecting to something you know works, like [smtp4dev](https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev).
- Enable logging like so, `new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger(Console.OpenStandardError()))`, then paste the output here.
- Using a helper package like [MailKitSimplified.Sender](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKitSimplified.Sender) would make this much simpler:

```
using var smtpSender = SmtpSender.Create("sigmaworldco.com", 465, "info@sigmaworldco.com", "**********", "");

var attachments = message.Attachments.Select(a => EmailWriter.GetMimePart(a.Stream, a.FileName, a.ContentType, a.ContentId));

await smtpSender.WriteEmail
    .From("info@sigmaworldco.com")
    .To("user@example.com")
    .Subject("sigmaworldco")
    .BodyText("Plain text here")
    .BodyHtml("HTML text here<br>")
    .Attach(attachments)
    .TrySendAsync();
```

Note: I wrote the library so I'm open to feature requests.